# C language and strings

Tags: c, initialization, substring, c-strings, strstr

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s3[12]="ABCDEISHERO";    
    char s4[5]="ABCDE";
    char* p=strstr(s3,s4);
    printf("%s",p);

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code, but according to the functionality of `strstr`, we have substring `"ABCDE"` in string `s3`, but why is the output `(null)`? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Tip: Don't declare strings with fixed lengths like this. Use `char s[] = "..."` and let the compiler figure it out for you. You've guessed the lengths wrong here. If you don't need a mutable character buffer, just use `char* s = "..."` instead.

Comment: Your arrays sizes do not account for null-terminator.

Comment: `s4` needs to be 6 elements wide to account for the string terminator - `strstr` isn't matching it because (most likely) there are one or more non-zero bytes following the last character, so `strstr` sees `s4` as `"ABCDEandabunchofothercharacters"`, not `"ABCDE"`.

Comment: @tadman No, use `const char *s = "..."`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Ideally, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> `s4` needs to be 6 elements wide to account for the string terminator - `strstr` isn't matching it because (most likely) there are one or more non-zero bytes following the last character, so `strstr` sees `s4` as `"ABCDE???????"`, not `"ABCDE"`.

Answered by John Bode.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
char s4[5]="ABCDE";
```

is valid in C but is not valid in C++.

The problem with this declaration is that the array `s4` does not contain a string. In C "a string" means "a null-terminated sequence of bytes", and `s4` does not have a space to accommodate the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal `"ABCDE"` used as an initializer.

Thus calling the function `strstr` that expects that the both arguments will be pointers to strings results in undefined behavior.

Either write

```
char s4[6]="ABCDE";
```

or even better

```
char s4[]="ABCDE";
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s3[12] = "ABCDEISHERO";    
    char s4[] = "ABCDE";

    char* p = strstr( s3, s4 );

    if ( p ) printf( "%s\n", p );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ABCDEISHERO
```

because the returned by the call of the function `strstr` pointer `p` points to the beginning of the character array `s3`.

Comment: Edited your answer to explain what a C-string is. If OP had to ask that question, they probably don't know the formal definition.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for appending the answer.